# Unable to upload photo in android 12 getting java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString

Tags: android

This is my code i am trying to upload image to server.

// Image Capture using

```
 Matisse.from(UploadPanActivity.this)
                            .choose(MimeType.ofImage())
                            .countable(true).capture(false)
                            .maxSelectable(1)
                            .gridExpectedSize(300)
                            .restrictOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
                            .thumbnailScale(0.85f)
                            .imageEngine(new GlideEngine())
                            .showPreview(false) // Default is `true`
                            .forResult(21);
```

// Result Inform

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("AAkash " + requestCode);
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
        File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
        if (requestCode == 21 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            sendPan(userDetails.getuserid(), "8", Matisse.obtainPathResult(data).get(0), "pan_photo");
        }
        
    }
```

// to get image URl

```
 public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        Bitmap OutImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, 1000, 1000, true);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), OutImage, "easy_loan_profile_pic", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

// getImage path using URI

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        String path = "";
        if (getContentResolver() != null) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                path = cursor.getString(idx);
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

When i am trying to upload image i am getting Error below :

```
2022-11-15 12:27:13.220 25887-24114/com.app.zeis E/sqlite3_android: [IKR-38846] ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2022-11-15 12:27:15.951 25887-25887/com.app.zeis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.zeis, PID: 25887
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=22, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.app.zeis/com.app.zeis.UploadPanActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5261)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8024)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:496)
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:486)
        at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:458)
        at com.app.zeis.UploadPanActivity.getImageUri(UploadPanActivity.java:314)
        at com.app.zeis.UploadPanActivity.onActivityResult(UploadPanActivity.java:233)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5261) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8024) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978) 
2022-11-15 12:27:16.086 25887-24114/com.app.zeis E/sqlite3_android: [IKR-38846] ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
```

'
this error is am getting only in android 11, 12 not other device other device i am  able to upload please help me what i am doing wrong with 11, 12 Os version in android .

Comment: `String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver()` It looks as if `path` becomes `null`.

Comment: Further i see a getRealPathFromURI which you never should use.

Comment: what we need to use can you please help me in this

Comment: can you please help how to get real path of image using content URI?

Comment: Use the uri directly. You dont need a 'real path'. And it is unclear to me about which image you are talking.

Comment: I am getting this Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: 8: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Well which `file` are you talking about? Which file is not found? Tell the path or scheme you used for that action.

Comment: I have used this code to get dat the path using URI https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626?permalink_comment_id=3702673

Comment: You are not giving the info i asked for and please do not post links. I will not read them.